# Layout breaks when repeaters model updated

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a `Repeater` nested in a `ColumnLayout`. This `Repeater` has a delegate - `Rectangle` with a `Label` within it. The problem is that when the model is updated, the last `Rectangle` disappears (`Label` stays visible). Code goes like that:

```
Repeater {
    id: rep
    model: myModel

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: parent.width
        height: lab.implicitHeight + 25

        color: "yellow"
        border {
            width: 1
            color: "green"
        }

        Label {
            id: lab
            text: label
        }
    }
}
```

The problems occurs only on model update while panel is opened, when created it looks ok.

Comment: Sorry, I can not provide whole and exact code

Comment: No one asked for your super-secret enterprise data (lol) just a minimum example showing the problem. You were like that the answerer guessed the right answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the attached properties solves the problem:

```
Rectangle {
      id: rect
      Layout.fillWidth: true
      Layout.preferredHeight: lab.implicitHeight + 25

      color: "yellow"
      ...
}
```